Why do we need Bob's measurement for Quantum Teleportation
In this Qiskit community tutorial on Quantum Teleportation (QT), the Step 5 in In [3] asks to measure Bob's final state.
circuit.measure([2], [2])

But I have a basic question: Why do we need to measure the final state at all? Won't that collapse the quantum state? If the original state (initially in Alice's lab) is a superposition state, won't Bob lose the state after he measures it?
On the other hand, in the Bell state generation tutorial, no measurement is done explicitly (except through the simulator, see In [11] to In [13]). So why does the QT require the line circuit.measure([2], [2])?
Let me add a coding example below for more clarity and an awaited discussion.
## ---  Module imports ----------------------

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

# Visualization
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex, plot_histogram

# Simulator
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator 

# Others 
from IPython.display import Markdown
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline


## ----- CODE FOR GENERATION OF BELL STATE |Phi+> -------

# Create a quantum circuit for 2 qubits
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

# Apply H-gate to the first qubit:
qc.h(0)

# Apply a CNOT:
qc.cx(0,1)

# Show circuit
display(qc.draw('mpl'))

simulator = AerSimulator() # need to import AerSimulator 

# Save the statevector into the quantum circuit
qc.save_statevector()


# Transpile the circuit for the simulator
qc = transpile(qc, simulator)

# Run on the simulator/backend
job = simulator.run(qc, shots=100).result() # some define variable `result` as well 

# Get final statevector from job
final_state_1 = job.get_statevector()
print('Final state =',final_state_1)
display( Markdown(r'Two qubit state ='), final_state_1.draw('latex') )
array_to_latex(final_state_1, prefix="(\\text{Two qubit state})^T = ")

# Get counts and plot histogram 
plot_histogram(job.get_counts())

This gives us the plot shown below.

Now the following is the code for Quantum Teleportation where I have intentionally commented out the line containing Bob's measurement [# qc.measure(2,2)].
## --- QUANTUM TELEPORTATION CODE ----------

# Create a quantum circuit for 3 qubits and their measurements

qc = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)


# Prepare mysterious state |Q>  
choice = 0 # default choice |Q> = |0>
choice = 1  # |Q> = |1>
choice = 2 # |Q> = (|0> + |1>)/sqrt(2)
choice = 3; a = 0.8; b = np.sqrt(1-a*a)
           # |Q> = a|0> + b|1> [generic superposition]

choice = 1
if choice == 0:
  print('|Q > = |0 >')
elif choice == 1:
  qc.x(0) 
  print('|Q > = |1 >') 
elif choice == 2:
  qc.h(0) 
  print(f'|Q > = .70710678|0 > + .70710678|1 >')
else:
  theta = 2*np.arccos(a); phi = 0
  qc.u(theta, phi, 0, 0) 
  print(f'|Q > = {a}|0 > + {b}|1 >')
display(qc.draw('mpl'))


# Check initial state |\psi>
psi = Statevector(qc)
print(psi)
display(Markdown(r'Initial three qubit state ='),psi.draw('latex'))
array_to_latex(psi, prefix="(\\text{Three qubit state})^T = ")

###  Step 1: create an entangled Bell pair between Alice and Bob (q1 & q2)
qc.h(1)
qc.cx(1,2)
qc.barrier() # put a barrier to demarcate


### Step 2: Alice applies a series of operations between the state to teleport (q0) 
###.       and her half of the Bell pair (q1)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.barrier()
qc.h(0)
qc.barrier() # put a barrier to visualize 


### Step 3: Alice measures on q0 and q1, sends the results to Bob as classical bits
#qc.measure([0, 1], [0, 1]) # results stored in classical bits 0 and 1, respectively
qc.measure(0,0)
qc.measure(1,1)
qc.barrier()
qc.draw('mpl')

### Step 4: Based on Alice's results, Bob performs gates 
qc.cx(1,2)
qc.cz(0,2)
qc.draw('mpl')

### Step 5: Bob measures (does he need to?)
# qc.measure(2,2)

display(qc.draw(output='mpl'))


### Now check the state through quantum silmulator
simulator = AerSimulator() # need to import AerSimulator 

# Save the statevector into the quantum circuit
qc.save_statevector() # 


# Transpile the circuit for the simulator
qc = transpile(qc, simulator)

# Run job on the simulator/backend 
job = simulator.run(qc, shots=100).result() 

# Get final statevector from job
final_state_2 = job.get_statevector()
print('Final state =',final_state_2)
display( Markdown(r'Three qubit state ='), final_state_2.draw('latex') )
array_to_latex(final_state_2, prefix="(\\text{Three qubit state})^T = ")



# Get counts and plot histogram
plot_histogram(job.get_counts())

I get the following output.


As it can be seen, the final statevector after Bob's gate operations is correctly produced ($|Q\rangle = 1$). However, that is not reflected in the histogram plot through the simulator and we get incorrect counts.
I also noticed that in the first code (Bell state generation), our quantum circuit does not contain any classical register while the second code (Quantum teleportation) has 3 classical registers. That's why we see "quasi-probability" in the first case and "count" in the second case. But does it make any big difference?

You are right that if Alice were to send an arbitrary state, measuring $q_2$ would collapse it. In practice, Bob wouldn't directly measure $q_2$ after applying the relevant corrections, but would use it for some other purposes.
The point of the measurement in this tutorial is to demonstrate that $q_2$ is not random, but indeed corresponds to the state Alice sent at the beginning. Since Alice send $|1\rangle$, the distribution of measurement should only include outcomes with a $1$ for the measurement of $q_2$, which is shown on the graph of the following section.
These two experiments are quite small, so it is easy for computers (and fairly easy for humans) to derive what the final state is. This kind of derivation can be done with QuantumCircuit.save_statevector() for example, without needing to perform any final measurement. This method is exact (up to floating-point errors), but involves tracking an exponential number of coefficients, so it isn't suitable for larger circuits.
Qiskit is a quantum computation framework, so it allows for the simulation of the behavior of a quantum computer that would run a given circuit. A quantum computer does not mathematically derive the final state, but runs the quantum gates of a circuit and performs some measurements whose outcomes are stored in some classical registers. Quantum measurements are inherently probabilistic, so a significant number of runs $N$ (shots) need to be simulated for the distribution to be representative of the true underlying unknown state. This method is statistical and therefore approximate. If the state includes some very unlikely outcomes (with squared amplitude below $\frac{1}{N}$), you might miss them, just like you would miss them on a real quantum computer.
The distribution that you get out of this simulator corresponds to the read classical registers of the QuantumCircuit object simulated, if some classical registers are defined in it. In your second experiment, you never store any quantum measurement outcome in the third classical register, so it will always be sampled as $0$. Try to initialize qc with QuantumCircuit(3, 2) or QuantumCircuit(3, 4) and you will see the labels of the histogram changing accordingly. You need to include the qc.measure(2, 2) to see for yourself that the quantum teleportation worked.
Why does the simulation of the Bell state circuit outputs the correct histogram, then?
My guess is that when a circuit with no defined classical registers is simulated, qiskit automatically adds a measurement of all the qubits in the $Z$ basis at the end and samples these measurements.
Regarding the difference of used terminology between "Quasi-probabilities" vs "Counts", I would say that quasi-probabilities corresponds to counts divided by total number of shots. My uneducated guess is that the handling of a circuit with no classical registers has for side effect to output the result as quasi-probabilities instead of counts.

Then why don't we need to measure separately for the Bell's state? What does the simulator do? Aren't the counts based on multiple shots of measurements?

You do not need measurements to prepare the Bell state, this can be done only with $H$ and $CNOT$ gate. As I said, in a real case scenario, neither the $q2$ measurement of QT nor the measurements of the Bell state would be done, they are only included to demonstrate everything went according to plan. Simulators like In[5]or In[9] directly compute the statevector or the circuit operator without requiring shots to be drawn. They are more precise but computationally expensive. On a real quantum computer, only shots can be performed.

Still confusing. Why can't "directly compute the statevector or the circuit operator without requiring shots" in the QT case? Aren't both to verify the state has been produced correctly or not? I used to believe that result.get_counts are done from multiple measurements through the simulator and each measurement is termed a shot. Correct me if I am wrong.

You could, the tutorial just doesn't do it. What I call simulators are mathematical proof (mathematically computing the statevector), while shots are statistical proofs (you could miss a very unlikely outcome). But in some sense, the shots are a simulation of what you would get with a noiseless quantum computer.

Please check the edited version of my question. I have added codes for Bell states and QT now. The simulator part is the same in both cases. However, there is a difference in the QuantumCircuit registers. Thanks.

@hbaromega See my edits summarizing the clarifications done in the comments and adressing your edited question.
